# I want to make a copy with postgres

Tags: postgresql, symfony

I want to integrate a postgres request in symfony with the statement, however I can't communicate the right path for the copy

```
$RAW_QUERY = 'copy data(subject,predicate,object,lang) from :text DELIMITER \';\' CSV HEADER';
        
        $statement = $this->emi->getConnection()->prepare($RAW_QUERY);
        $statement->bindValue('text', $this->params->get('kernel.project_dir') . '/imports/flux.csv');
        $statement->executeStatement();
```

error:

```
SQLSTATE[42601]: Syntax error: 7 ERROR:  syntax error at or near "$1"    
  LINE 1: copy data(subject,predicate,object,lang) from $1 DELIMITER '...  
                                                    ^
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The COPY filename is not a substitutable parameter, and COPY itself is not a preparable command.  You will have to interpolate the filename into the command and run it directly.